# Strange behavior when sending USSD codes (Android)

Tags: android, ussd

I have application, which sends some USSD codes. In one type of situation, from user actions with interface, in another - when some SMS (with wildcard) received.

I have a code for sending USSD:

```
private static void setCallDivert (Context context, String phoneNo) {
    String callForwardString = "**21*" + phoneNo + "#";
    Log.i("Call forward string", callForwardString);

    Intent intentCallForward = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intentCallForward.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Uri uri2 = Uri.fromParts("tel", callForwardString, "#");
    intentCallForward.setData(uri2);                                
    context.startActivity(intentCallForward);
    divertDbRecord (context, true, phoneNo);
}
```

When it called from button onClick method, it working okay.

When it called from SMS Handler, message "Call forwarding Connection problem or invalid MMI code" appear.

In logcat, I can see a request. It is a same, in both situations.

Of course, I testing it on real Android phone, not on emulator.

Maybe, someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode your Uri hash

```
public static final String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
```

This allows the dialler to interpret the # value correctly